# An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'production' is not set in the workspace

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular8, dev-to-production

Hi Created one project in Angular 8.
Initially it was supporting only one default language (US-EN). then I applied localization.

before localization for preparing production build, I used to give following command.

```
ng build --prod --base-href "/Windchill/com/qiwkCollaborator/"
```

after localization, I made some changes in the angular.json and in package.json. after making these changes whenever I am giving any command to prepare to build it is giving me the following error.

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'production' is not set in the workspace.
```

some portion of Package.json file is as follows:

```
"name": "qwik-collaborator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-locale:en": "ng build --prod --i18n-locale en --i18n-format xlf --i18n-file src/translate/messages.en.xlf --output-path=dist/en --baseHref /en/",
    "build-locale:fr": "ng build --prod --i18n-locale fr --i18n-format xlf --i18n-file src/translate/messages.fr.xlf --output-path=dist/fr --baseHref /fr/"
```

some portion of Angular.json file is as follows.

```
"build": {

          "configurations": {
            "fr": {
            "aot": true,
            "outputPath": "dist/qwikCollaborator/fr/",
            "i18nFile": "src/translate/messages.fr.xlf",      
            "i18nFormat": "xlf",      
            "i18nLocale": "fr",      
            "i18nMissingTranslation": "error"    
             },
             "en": {
            "aot": true,
            "outputPath": "dist/qwikCollaborator/en/",
            "i18nFile": "src/translate/messages.en.xlf",      
            "i18nFormat": "xlf",      
            "i18nLocale": "en",      
            "i18nMissingTranslation": "error"    
             }  
           },
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/qwikCollaborator",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/css/custom-mobile.css",
              "src/assets/css/custom.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/qwikCollaborator.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
          "es5": {
        "tsConfig": "./tsconfig.es5.json"
      },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
.......


"serve": {
           "configurations": {
            "fr": {
            "browserTarget": "qwikCollaborator:build:fr" 
            },
            "en": {
            "browserTarget": "qwikCollaborator:build:en" 
            } ,
            },
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "qwikCollaborator:build"
          },

          "configurations": {
          "es5": {
        "browserTarget": "qwikCollaborator:build:es5"
      },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "qwikCollaborator:build:es5"
            }
          }
        },
```

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are building with `--prod`, which means to use the `production` configuration, which you obviously removed

You need to change your build scripts to

```
"build-locale:en": "ng build -c en --output-path=dist/en --baseHref /en/",
"build-locale:fr": "ng build -c fr --output-path=dist/fr --baseHref /fr/"
```

Options that are specified in `angular.json` (like file i18n file format and locations) do not need to be specified again in the build command

If you want to build using `ng build --prod` as before, you just need to add the `production` configuration back into the `build` target

Comment: I tried with the above method but it is giving me the error "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:" after deployment of the build on the server-side. can you please check where I need to make changes in this
?

Comment: That'd be a different question, but you probably need to modify your nginx (or other webserver) rules to redirect to the correct bundle based on the requested url